# Deriving posterior mean with horseshoe prior

Tags: bayesian, expected-value, prior, regularization

I want to decompose a matrix $S \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times D}$ as below
$$S=vv^T $$
where  $v_i\mid\lambda_i,\tau_i \sim N(0,\lambda^2_i\rho^2_i)$, $\lambda_i \sim Cauchy^+(0,1)$ i.e $v$ has horseshoe prior and $i$ goes from 1 to $D$. I would be really grateful of someone can give a pointer on how to find the $\mathbb{E}(S)$?

Comment: There is an issue with the definition of $v$ which is a vector in $S$ but distributed from a scalar distribution.

Comment: @Xi'an Updated the question.

Comment: You probably solved the problem by now, but I believe this kind of problem can only be solved with approximations such as MCMC